# How to search a list in excel against list of words to filter out

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search a list to filter out if it contains certain words.

I found this VBA script

```
Sub GetWords()

    Dim wrdLRow As Integer
    Dim wrdLp As Integer
    Dim CommentLrow As Integer
    Dim CommentLp As Integer
    Dim fndWord As Integer
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next 'Suppress Errors... for when we don't find a match

    'Define worksheet that has data on it....
    Set Sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Get last row for words based on column A
    wrdLRow = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Get last row for comments based on column C
    CommentLrow = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop through lists and find matches....
    For CommentLp = 2 To CommentLrow

        For wrdLp = 2 To wrdLRow

            'Look for word...
            fndWord = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A"), Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "C"))

            'If we found the word....then
            If fndWord > 0 Then
                Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "D") = Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "D") & "; " & Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
                fndWord = 0 'Reset Variable for next loop
            End If

        Next wrdLp

        Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "D") = Mid(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "D"), 3, Len(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "D")) - 2)

    Next CommentLp

End Sub
```

Before image

[image]

After image

[image]

It not only searches for words but also for characters inside words.

If the string in col C is "How can i make excel to search word against a list of words?"

and the words to look for in col A are "how, ke, cel, abcd, xyz"

then this will return "how; ke; cel;".

I want only "how" not the char "ke;cel;" inside the words "make;excel".

This might be done by modifying this script, so it returns only words if it contains space either before of after the word, so it can be guessed as the whole word instead of characters.

Comment: This is not a fancy answer, but you could probably just put four different versions of the word in column. For example "Yes"..." Yes"..."Yes "..." Yes ". For the one with no spaces, restrict matches to items in column C to strings with no spaces. Of course doing this in script is a better idea, but this would work if you don't have the time to code it all out. To prevent the creation of duplicates in your final string in column D, use the `Instr` function to check if the substring exists before appending it.

Comment: i already tried it before posting here, what prob it contain is like suppose 2 strings are 
"ABCD EFGH QRST" 
"XYZ EF GH RS T"
and i want to search  "RS" so according to your solution if i put four different verstion of like "RS" " RS" "RS " " RS "

than it will return both the above string containing RS word.
here string 1 as QRST, which is wrong return and string 2 has right return

and there is one more prob with your solution... i might like it will search the same list with 4 times and suppose  word 1st "RSAFRS " and " RSSFAR" will also retun true, 

which i dont wont

Comment: @DH123 "i might like it will search the same list" what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `InStr function`. Have in mind that `InStr function` is case sensitive.

The below is just a sample. modify and use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim arr_For As Variant, arr_In As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Position As Long
    Dim Valid As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr_For = .Range("A1:A5")
        arr_In = .Range("B1:B5")

        For i = LBound(arr_For) To UBound(arr_For)

            For j = LBound(arr_In) To UBound(arr_In)

                Position = InStr(arr_In(j, 1), arr_For(i, 1))

                If Position > 0 Then

                    Valid = False

                    If Position = 1 And Mid(arr_In(j, 1), Position + Len(arr_For(i, 1)), 1) = " " Then
                        Valid = True
                    ElseIf Position > 1 Then
                        If Position + Len(arr_For(i, 1)) = Len(arr_In(j, 1)) + 1 And Mid(arr_In(j, 1), Position - 1, 1) = " " Then
                            Valid = True
                        ElseIf Mid(arr_In(j, 1), Position - 1, 1) = " " And Mid(arr_In(j, 1), Position + Len(arr_For(i, 1)), 1) = " " Then
                            Valid = True
                        End If
                    End If

                    If Valid = True Then

                        If .Cells(j, 3).Value = "" Then
                            .Cells(j, 3).Value = arr_For(i, 1)
                        Else
                            .Cells(j, 3).Value = .Cells(j, 3).Value & " ; " & arr_For(i, 1)
                        End If

                    End If

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: not working, i mean still its finding character inside the words, and btw i need solution without case sensitive finder

Comment: Replace `If InStr(arr_In(j, 1), arr_For(i, 1) ) > 0 Then` with `If InStr(arr_In(j, 1), arr_For(i, 1) & " ") > 0 Then`

Comment: didnt worked, its still not checking the front space, i want it like either space before or after with word to match with list.

Comment: i think this worked, i'll need to check with my huge list, it might take some time, i'll update you ASAP, and many thanks for your time and update

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this and edit it a bit:
[image]

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(B$2,$A3,1),0),1,"")
```

You could return the letter by changing the ",1," to ",B$2," and perhaps consider concatenating several together if a non vba solution can be considered.

Edit, just to show its flexibility:
[image]

Comment: i didnt understand what your formula is doing, against which list of words its searching ? can you elaborate a lit bit or perhaps real looking example.

btw i want it to search for whole word not the char containing inside word

like "ABCD" not the individual "A" , "B" ...

Comment: @DH try using the find() function by itself, then the rest is obvious. Find() has 3 arguments, "find_text", "within_text", "start_num". "Find_text" is the text you are looking for in the target which is "within_text". Start_num is the position you want to start looking - the first position usually.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

---

***<sub>Sample Data:</sub>***

[image]

---

***<sub>Sample Code:</sub>***

```
Sub GetWords()

Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, x As Long
Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
Dim hits As String

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName

    'Get list of words to check
    lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A2:A" & lr1).Value

    'Get list of sentences to check
    lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = .Range("C2:D" & lr2).Value

    'Loop through all sentences in memory
    For x = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        For Each itm In arr1
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(itm, Split(arr2(x, 1), " "), 0)) Then
                If hits <> "" Then
                    hits = hits & "; " & itm
                Else
                    hits = itm
                End If
            End If
        Next itm
        arr2(x, 2) = hits
        hits = ""
    Next x

    'Load hits into column D
    .Range("C2:D" & lr2).Value = arr2

End With

End Sub
```

---

***<sub>Sample Result:</sub>***

[image]

---

It has gotten a bit extensive but I just wanted to go through it step-by-step with some explainations of what is happening.